# How to check if a library is installed?

Tags: linux, libraries

In Linux, how do I check if a library is installed or not? (from the command line of course).

In my specific case now, I want to check whether libjpeg is installed.

Comment: What distribution are you using ?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

To do this in a distro-independent* fashion you can use ldconfig with grep, like this:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg
```

If libjpeg is not installed, there will be no output. If it is installed, you will get a line for each version available.

Replace libjpeg by any library you want, and you have a generic, distro-independent* way of checking for library availability.

If for some reason the path to ldconfig is not set, you can try to invoke it using its full path, usually `/sbin/ldconfig`.

**99% of the times*

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Great!

Comment: Except for NixOS :-(

Comment: It's not possible to use this for checking for the dev version (headers) of a library, right?

Comment: @andig for that you my try something like "find /usr/include/ -iname \*jpeg\*".

Comment: Can you specify **99% times**? `bash: ldconfig: command not found` on Debian x64 Jessie with xfce! This is the recomended debian release on the debian website...

Comment: Are you really asking me if at June 6, 2013 (one month after Debian Whezzy was released, almost two years before Jessie was released), I experimented all existing Linux distros and concluded that the suggested command worked on 99% of them? The answer is no, of course not. It is a figure of speech. Read it like: "It works in most distributions".

Comment: However, even though I don't have access to a Debian Jessie right now, googling for "debian jessie ldconfig" will tell us that ldconfig is in the `libc-bin` package, which is an *essential* package, which means it should be available by default. Maybe it's a problem with your specific installation then? Maybe `sudo apt-get install libc-bin` will do the trick? Best regards.

Comment: @TomášZato: `ldconfig` is not available (`command not found` shows up) if you try to run it without being superuser.

Comment: Are there any equivalent of ldconfig for MacOS?

Comment: `/sbin/ldconfig -p` works for me without needing to be root.

Comment: If you're scripting this, you get the path via `ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg | cut -d' ' -f4`

Comment: A big caveat here is that the ldconfig approach does not take into consideration any libraries which are installed in "non-standard" locations and located by the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable mechanism. (Or at least not on my machine.)

Comment: [Fix for the LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410931/133603)

Answer (score 36):

You can check with the package manager of your distribution (aptitude, yum, ...) but as you did not give your distribution I can't give you the right command.

Another way can be to run `gcc -ljpeg`, if you get 'ld: library not found for -ljpeg' it means that gcc has not found the library (but it don't mean that it's not installed), if you get something like 'Undefined symbols: "_main", referenced from: ...' it means that libjpeg has been found.

`locate libjpeg; ls /usr/lib/libjpeg*; ls /lib/libjpeg*` are some other way to find if the lib in installed in the system

There are many other ways to check that, if you give us more context (why you need to check if libjpeg is installed) we could give you the best solution for your specific case.

Answer (score 19):

I use the **whereis** utility.

Sample:

```
l1feh4ck3r@xxx:~$ whereis libjpeg
libjpeg: /usr/lib/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/libjpeg.a /usr/lib/libjpeg.la
```

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 15):

I use this:

```
gcc -lpng
```

When the lib is installed, it yields:

```
undefined reference to 'main'
```

When the lib is **not** installed:

```
cannot find -lpng
```

Comment: This one is short and usefull

Comment: Thanks, [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/357543/197563) gave me a positive result, but this gave me a negative one.... Suppose you're trying to install something from source rpm (say x:s) (of which this q is one of several I encountered), and this pkg has dependencies which I choose the binary version to install (say y:b, z:b, w:b). If w,y, or z depends on x:b as well..... it's easier let it install, that's what I needed to do. Downloading and installing rpm manually without dependency checking didn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

For deb-based distribution you can do

```
dpkg -s packagename
```

Or if you know the filename only, use

```
locate filename
```

The filename is usually libsomething.so[.version].

Comment: The filename can also be something like "libsomething.a" for static version.

Comment: I find `dpkg -s` limited in utility, because it wants the actual package name, which may differ subtly or significantly from the library itself.  I use `dpkg -s|grep LIBRARY`

Comment: @dinomite apt-file is your friend :)

Comment: @DrewStephens doing that gives `dpkg-query: error: --status needs at least one package name argument`

Answer (score 8):

On Redhat based systems, one can use pkg-config to verify if a library is installed or not. Many rpm binaries actually make the same checks before proceeding with installation, so we can  reasonably rely on its veracity.

```
pkg-config --cflags jpeg

pkg-config --libs jpeg

pkg-config --cflags "jpeg >= 1.0.0" # for version check
pkg-config  --modversion jpeg | awk -F. '{ printf "0x%02X%02X%02X\n",$1,$2,$3 }' #version check
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done by configuration tools on linux all the time.

Look at this [**Tutorial about autoconf and KDevelop**](http://www.kdevelop.org/index.html?filename=3.0/doc/tutorial_autoconf.html).

Other tricks would use commands like `ldconfig` and `dpkg`.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04, I am able to display a wealth of relevant information for a package using aptitude.

```
% aptitude show libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev                      
Version: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 8,006 k
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Suggests: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
Breaks: libssl-dev:i386 (!= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Replaces: libssl-dev:i386 (< 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over
 the Internet. 
 
 It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl and libcrypto.
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
```

To find which package would provide a particular file I have found `apt-file` very useful - some instructions are here: https://linuxhint.com/find_which_package_contains_specific_file_ubuntu/

```
% apt-file search 'libjpeg.so'          
darktable: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/darktable/plugins/imageio/format/libjpeg.so
libjpeg-turbo8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg-turbo8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.2.2
libjpeg-turbo8-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
libjpeg62: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
libjpeg62: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
libjpeg62-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
libjpeg9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9
libjpeg9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9.4.0
libjpeg9-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
libxine2-misc-plugins: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xine/plugins/2.7/xineplug_decode_libjpeg.so
nsight-systems: /usr/lib/nsight-systems/Host-x86_64/libjpeg.so.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using dpkg to check whether it is installed.

`dpkg --list | grep [some_key_words_of_your_lib]`

Besides, on CentOS, you can try this.

`rpm -qa [lib_name]`

Comment: Note: Will work only for Debian based distros

Comment: @ALex_hha Yes, thank you, this should be emphasized.      On CentOS or red hat based systems, use `pkg-config` instead.

Answer (score 0):

as per Kim above

> dpkg -s packagename

```
[[ $(dpkg -s libsox-fmt-pulse 2> /dev/null) =~ "is not installed" ]] && sudo apt install libsox-fmt-pulse # for hdmi output
```